# How to solve this Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus

$ g: \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ , class $C^{2}$ , with Mclaurin polynomial of degree 2 is $p(x,y)= 3 x + 2y - x^ {2} + y^ {2} - 2 xy $ .

Let $ f (x,y) = ln (1+ g (x, y))$. Find the Mclaurin polynomial of degree 2 for f.

I need a hint, i am not sure about how to start

Comment: Hint. Note that $g(0,0)=0$. What is the McLaurin polynomial of degree 2 of $\ln(1+t)$? Now give it a try and show your work.

Comment: Let $g_x(x,y)=3-2x-2y$ and $g_y(x,y)=2+2y-2x$ be the derivatives of $g$ with respect to $x$ and $y$. You can compute the first few terms of the series of $f_x(x,y)=\frac{g_x(x,y)}{1+g(x,y)}$ by doing (two steps of) long division. Then you integrate with respect to $x$. This will give you the series of $f$ except for the terms that don't depend on $x$: $a_0+a_1y+a_2y^2$. Those you can get by the same procedure done on $f_y(x,y)=\frac{g_y(x,y)}{1+g(x,y)}$. Alternatively, you can also compute the second derivatives $f_{xx},f_{yy}, f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ and evaluate all the derivates at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: @RobertZ hi , i tried and i got this $p(x,y) = f(0,0) + \frac{1}{1+t} x - \frac{(1+t)^-2}{2}x^2 $ .

Comment: @Boxwood Thanks, i'll try on that way